# JQuery uploadify not working with https in an asp.net MVC3 application throwing error 2038

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, https, uploadify, adfs

I build a new MVC3 application and used Uploadify plugin in it. It works great. Below is my code:

```
 $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
        'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Uploader.swf")',
        'buttonText': 'Browse',
        'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/Images/cancel.png")',
        'script': 'Home/Upload',
        'fileDesc': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.eml;*.msg;*.doc;*.docx;*.pdf;*.txt;*.xps;*.zip;*.ppt;*.pptx;*.pages;*.numbers;*.url;*.xls;*.xlsx;',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.eml;*.msg;*.doc;*.docx;*.pdf;*.txt;*.xps;*.zip;*.ppt;*.pptx;*.pages;*.numbers;*.url;*.xls;*.xlsx;',
        'multi': false,
        'auto': true,
        'sizeLimit': 102400,
        'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
            alert(errorObj.info);
            alert(errorObj.text);
            alert(errorObj.status);
            if (errorObj.type == "File Size") {
                alert(errorObj.type + ' Limit: ' + Math.round(errorObj.sizeLimit / 1024) + 'KB');
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the method use to upload the file.

```
 public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
            //var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
            var fileName = "C:/temp/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName);
            fileData.SaveAs(fileName);

            return "ok";
        }
```

However when I use the same code in another MVC3 application that is federated using ADFS and uses https it always throws Error 2038. Does anyone know why I am getting this error. I have checked each and every configuration settings. Is this a security issue? Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: WIF errors start with ID and ADFS errors start with MSIS or ADMIN so it's none of these.

Comment: I somehow feel its security related. WIF is not throwing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue with self-signed certificates, look at this: [Uploadify error #2038](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332098/uploadify-error-2038)