# Uploadify error #2038

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Whenever I do a test with this script it continually fails at the upload attempt and gives the error IO #2038
The thing I can say for sure is it never even gets to the backend script of 'Upload.ashx'
Which that tells me it is a problem is with the script somehow. Now I am doing this with localhost on my test machine.

http://www.uploadify.com

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Uploadify/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#file_upload').uploadify({

                'uploader': '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'script': 'Upload.ashx',
                'multi': false,
                'sizeLimit': 10000000,
                'scriptAccess': 'sameDomain',
                'cancelImg': '/uploadify/cancel.png',
                'onAllComplete': function (event, data) {
                    alert(data.filesUploaded + ' files uploaded successfully!');
                },
                'onCancel': function (event, ID, fileObj, data) {
                    alert('The upload of ' + fileObj.name + ' has been canceled!');
                },
                'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                    alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);
                },
                'onSelectOnce': function (event, data) {
                    alert(data.filesSelected + ' files were selected for upload.');
                },
                'auto': false

            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
 <span>
                    <label for="file_upload" title="Photo">
                        Photo</label>
                        <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
                        <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a>
</span>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using SSL? It could be a problem with your certificates. Check if your certificate is valid for the domain.

http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/6650